# Moving Sefer Torah with Tallis (source?)

Tags: minhag, travel, tallit-gadol, sefer-torah, protective-casing

Often times, when someone will move a Sefer Torah from one place to another, on top of what the Sefer Torah is already normally covered with, he will put an additional covering of a Tallis-Gadol. Where does this minhag come from? What is the reason for it?

Comment: Because he wants a second covering, and what else is usually near Torah scrolls and is big enough to cover it?

Comment: @DoubleAA and why does he want/need a second covering?

Comment: Perhaps in case you walk by unclean/immodest things/people/actions; alternatively, perhaps so people don't have to stand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Tzedaka U'Mishpot 16:2 note 3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8978&st=&pgnum=290) indictaes that he has been unable to find a source for this Minhag.

> וראיתי נוהגים כשמוליכים ס״ת ביחיד עוטפין אותו בטלית ולא מצאתי עדיין
>   מקור  לזה.‏
>
> I have seen people who wrap the Sefer Torah in a Tallis when they take
>   it from place to place; I have not yet found the source for this
>   custom.

Comment: How do you find these?!? (+1.)

Comment: @msh210 Piskei Teshuvas brings this I believe...

Comment: @Yehoshua: I found this online and did not see it in the Pischei Teshuvos.

Comment: @GershonGold so the question goes back then :).