# Why do we cover a Sefer Torah with a talis when traveling?

Tags: travel, tallit-gadol, sefer-torah, protective-casing

There's a widespread custom to cover a Sefer Torah with a talis when travelling.

**Has this custom been mentioned in halachic literature? Why is this done?**

The closest I found was [Shulchan Aruch, YD 482:8](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.282.8):

> בית שיש בו ס"ת לא ישמש בו מטתו עד שיוציאנו ואם אין לו מקום להוציאו
>   יעשה לפניו מחיצה גבוהה י' טפחים אבל ע"י הנחת כלי בתוך כלי שאינו מיוחד
>   אינו מותר אלא בתפילין ושאר כתבי הקדש וחומשים אבל לא בס"ת והרמב"ם מתיר
>   אף בס"ת ואם פירש טליתו על הארגז שמונח בו חשוב ככלי בתוך כלי
>
> If one is in a house that has a Sefer Torah in it, one may not have
>   marital relations until it is removed; and if there is no place to
>   remove it to, one may make a boundary (*mechitza*) that is ten
>   handbreadths tall. However, one may not place it into a (כלי בתוך כלי)
>   "vessel inside a vessel," because that only works to permit marital
>   relations for tefillin and other holy writings, and *chumashim*; but
>   not for a Sefer Torah. The Rambam permitted this even for a Sefer
>   Torah. If one places one's *tallis* on the chest (ארגז) that contains the
>   Sefer Torah, it is considered to be a "vessel inside a vessel."

(*my translation*)

However, this doesn't really discuss *travelling* with a Torah. Additionally, when travelling in public, there likely won't be anyone having marital relations (we hope); besides the fact that there is usually no ארגז (*according to Jastrow's translation of "box, chest"*) when travelling -- the Torah is usually wrapped in the tallis by itself and carried when travelling.

The Sefer is usually covered by the *mantel* (Sefer Torah cover) (*or the wooden case, for Sefaradi Sefarim*), so I don't think that it's to protect the Torah....are we trying to protect the *covering* of the Torah?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19128/5323

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21942/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, I think so. Why didn't that show up when I searched for it?